# Script throwing an error Error: ng:areq Bad Argument

Tags: angularjs

My html file look like this

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js">    </script>
<script src ="ang_script.js"> </script>

</head>
<body>
<div ng-app id="bootangular" ng-controller="firstcontroller"> 
<button ng-click="alertfunction()"> click me </button>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and the script file is as follows

```
 var app = angular.module("firstModule",[])
 app.controller("firstcontroller",['$scope',function($scope)
  {
   $scope.alertfunction=function()
    {
      alert("Done");
     };
  }])
```

This is throwing an error which takes me to this page https://docs.angularjs.org/error/ng/areq?p0=firstcontroller&p1=not%20a%20function,%20got%20undefined

which I am not able to understand

Comment: try moving ng-controller to a child html node and giving ng-app="firstModule"

Comment: add ';' after controller definition

Comment: and after ` var app = angular.module("firstModule",[])` - or delete `app` before controller definition

Answer (score 0):

You're not defining the `ng-app` correctly. Please update your HTML with below code

```
<div data-ng-app="firstModule" id="bootangular" data-ng-controller="firstcontroller"> 

</div>
```

And your controller code then work. I don't see any error in your controller's code.